# Why are so many soft interrupt when running Redis

Tags: redis, cpu-usage

When I run load test for Redis server, I found, the idle of cpu core which Redis server used is about 80 percent, however, the soft interrupt(si) is about ~40. I don't know why.

And I read some pages and i get that Redis server use network interrupt to get good performance. But I still do not understand. Could someone explain why Redis server uses so many soft interrupt? Many Thanks

Comment: Here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/memcached/OLLqktIN7Y4 is the good discussion about same issue to `memcached`(same for `Redis`). Also read http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-tcp-ip-network-stack/ to understand how this work at low level.

Answer (score 0):

Soft Interrupts is how the I/O event notification works on many OSes.  Redis is (mainly) single threaded.  By having only one thread you don't have to worry about concurrency issues.  So it uses epoll/kqueue on Linux/BSD respectively.  These kernel commands use soft interrupts by the kernel to notify the system when device driver either has completed sending I/O or is receiving.  It should use very little CPU because it is all I/O, very little of Redis is a CPU-bound problem.

TLDR: It's all I/O multiplexing underneath the redis covers.